# Is it enought to use just .click() to uncheck checkbox wrapped by jQuery UI checker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox

I usually check/uncheck checkboxes using this code:

```
$('.checkbox').prop('checked',true/false);
```

But if I use this code for checkbox wrapped by UI 'checker' div, it is not visually updated. 
I have noticed one more interesting thing: 
if I simply use click(), this checkbox is getting the right prop-checked and is visually updated:

```
$('.checkbox').click();
```

The form is being sent with correct values. Everything seems to work smoothly.

So I just want to make sure whether it is safe to use simple click() in this case. Or may be this way has some pitfalls?

Comment: What's a jQuery UI checker?

Answer (score 1):

> So I just want to make sure whether it is safe to use simple `click()` in this case.

It may well be, but I think I would lean toward doing something like this instead:

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.fn.checkButton) {
        $.fn.checkButton = function(val ) {
            return this.prop('checked', val).button('refresh');
        };
    }
}(jQuery);
```

Then:

```
$(".checkbox").checkButton(true/false);
```

The above assumes you're using `button` with checkboxes for toggled buttons, but it applies to any of the jQuery UI widgets (with the appropriate method change, swap `button` out for whatever a "checker" div is).

Obviously, the name of the plugin method can be whatever you want it to be (I'd be very, very tempted by `checked`)...

Answer (score -1):

For a situation like this, I would do something like

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', true/false);
});
```

This improves clarity while also making sure it does exactly what you want it to.